# is there a Json specification to describe formular ?

Tags: json, forms, specifications

I wonder if a Json specification exist to describe formular. 
For instance :

```
field {
   label: "your name"
   description : "This is the field to put your name"
   type: string 
   validator : "[a-z]*"
   default : "name .. ."
}
```

It will be use to create a TextLineEdit ! 
That's mean you can generate a complete formular from a json automatically.

Comment: yes, there are, but asking for documentation/libraries is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I found "Json Schema Forms" which is what I need. They are several online playground where you can test it. And JS/HTML library .